# How to calculate the reynolds number for airborne wind energy system?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, navier-stokes, laminar-flow

I am asking for some help on how to calculate the reynolds number for an AWES. I know the formula of Re=rho*v*l/viscosity. I have selected the air foil as Clark y with chord length 3.72m (which will be the characteristic length). I specifically need the values of rho, v, viscosity with changing altitude. And also if it is based on geographical location India it would be helpful.

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard to find on the internet. Where have you already looked?

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for Physics.SE

Comment: It is possible to use "typeset" [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in your posts here.   For example the [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) Re $= \rho u L/ \mu$ where $\rho$ is the density of the fluid, $u$ is the flow speed, $L$ is a characteristic length, and $\mu$ is dynamic viscosity gives a dimensionless quantity (when compatible units are used).  Note the slightly simpler expression in terms of kinematic viscosity $\nu$, Re $= u L/\nu$.  Viscosity of air varies with temperature and pressure, so more context is needed.